# How to reposition element retrieved by ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

As the title says, I am trying to manipulate an element that's being brought into the webpage after a form is submitted. It is an ajax response.

I know there's a different way of dealing with elements that are brought by ajax.

```
$('#cartx').html($('#cartcopy').html());
```

It is probably clear what I'm trying to do: update a shopping cart contents via ajax.
I keep getting this error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'html' of null
```

What can I do?

Later edit:

This is the code:

```
function hideJ2tOverlay(){
$('j2t-overlay').hide();
$('j2t_ajax_progress').hide();
$('j2t_ajax_confirm').hide();
  $('#cartx').html('test');

}
```

The website is skin79.ro

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Please show the rest of your code. The error listed is not related to the line shown (which will not cause that error, even if the ids do not exist)

Comment: Can you please post the entire JS which does AJAX & then DOM manipulation

Comment: The `html()` method sets or returns the content (innerHTML)

Comment: To reiterate: `$('#cartx').html($('#cartcopy').html());` will never cause an error, even if there is no `#cartcopy` element, as passing `undefined` to `html()` simply leaves the existing `innerHTML` intact. *You need to show the rest of your code & HTML* (or live with a load of down-votes) :)

Comment: skin79.ro - try to add products to cart and you will see.

Comment: Thank you for providing the link. After breakpointing at the error line, and inspecting the global variables, I noticed `$` was *not* the `jQuery` object. Answer to immediate error problem below.

Comment: +1 now you have a link to allow diagnosis of the problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you have another plugin (or code) that has set the global `$`, normally used by jQuery, to a function (or object) that is not jQuery.

You need to use `jQuery` and not `$` in your alert.

e.g.

```
  alert(jQuery('#cartcopy').html());
```

The nicer alternative is to locally scope a `$`, using this shortcut version of a DOM ready handler:

```
jQuery(function ($) {YOUR CODE HERE USING A LOCAL $});
```

e.g.

```
  jQuery(function ($) {
      setInterval(function () {
          alert($('#cartcopy').html());
      }, 1000);

      $('#brands-list').jcarousel({
          scroll: 2,

          auto: 3,
          wrap: 'circular',
          start: 1
      });
      $('#features-list').jcarousel({
          scroll: 2,

          auto: 3,

          wrap: 'circular',
          start: 1
      });
      $('#cartx').hover(function () {
          $(this).children('.cart-top-container').slideDown();
      }, function () {
          $(this).children('.cart-top-container').slideUp();
      });

  });
```

Then you can reference the shorter `$` inside the handler without concern over the other global `$`.

Comment: Another short thing: Now I managed to update the cart but on mouseover it doesn't slidedown the cart contents anymore. I know there is a different way of selecting elements that were moved around the page. How can I make it work again? Thanks.

Comment: @AndroPetre: You need to ask a *new* question for that. Happy to take a look at it when you post it.